# Android Studio import module (AAR) that has a sub module inside

Tags: android, android-studio, module

Is there a way to import a module (.aar) in Android Studio which also has an imported module? A structure like this

`[App-that-needs-module [moduleB [moduleA] ] ]`

`moduleB` has a dependency `moduleA` and works alright when running through a project of `moduleB`.

However, if I want to use the `moduleB` to a specific project, the `moduleA` isn't automatically included in the usage of `moduleB` and needs to be imported separately and looks like this:

`[App-that-needs-module [moduleB] [moduleA] ]`

Is there a way that when I import `moduleB`, it comes along with it `moduleA` since `moduleA` is defined as a dependency of `moduleB`?

Answer (score 0):

By default you will have to import both libraries since the dependencies of moduleB are not included in it's aar. If you're the owner of moduleB, you might re-built it including it's dependencies, so that you only have to import moduleB. Just Google for "fat aar", there are some tutorials out there.